# How to add more parameters on feathersjs service method with primus

Tags: feathersjs, primus

I checked this link https://docs.feathersjs.com/real-time/primus.html to setup additional parameters on service method but I didn't figure out how to do it.

Below is my service class:

```
create(id, shellId, params) {
     ...

  }
```

below is the primus configuration:

```
 app.configure(primus({
    transformer: 'websockets',
    timeout: false
  }, (primus) => {
    primus.library();
    primus.save(path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/primus.js'));
  }))
```

In the manual, it mentions something like below:

```
primus.use('todos::create', function(socket, done){
    // Exposing a request property to services and hooks
    socket.request.feathers.referrer = socket.request.referrer;
    done();
  });
```

but I am not sure what this function is doing. And also I tried to add above code in my application, I will get `socket.request` is undefined error. How to add more parameters on service class in this case?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The example is a [Primus middleware](https://github.com/primus/primus#primususename-fn-options-index) but I'm not sure that does what you are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to create a method like: `create(id, shellId, params)`. But I am not sure how to let feathersjs support these three parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the [official service methods](https://docs.feathersjs.com/services/readme.html#service-methods) and their signatures, in the case of `create` it is `data` for the entire data object and `params` for additional parameters. Your service class `create` looks something like this:

```
class MyService {
  create(data, params) {
    const { shellId, id } = data;
    // Do something here

    return Promise.resolve({ /* some data here */ });
  }  
}

app.use('/myservice', new MyService());
```

On the client you can use it through the [Feathers client](https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/primus.html) or a [direct Primus connection](https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/vanilla-primus.html) like this:

```
primus.send('myservice::create', {
  id: 'test',
  shellId: 'testing'
}, (error, data) => {
  console.log('Returned data', data);
});
```